# Python - Discord Bot Kill/Stop Another Running Function

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am wondering if it is possible to kill or stop a running function with a discord bot in Python. Ideally, the `execute` function would consist of a for loop and asyncio.sleep for a certain time. I would like the `abort` function to stop the `execute` function from continuing.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = discord.Bot()

# Execute Command
@bot.command()
async def execute(ctx, timer: discord.Option(int)):
    # Countdown from time given
    for i in range(timer, 0, -1):
        if int(i) == 1:
            await ctx.respond(f"Execution in {i} minute")
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            await ctx.respond(f"EXECUTE EXECUTE EXECUTE")
        else:
            await ctx.respond(f"Execution in {i} minutes")
            await asyncio.sleep(60)

@bot.command()
async def abort(ctx):
    # This will kill/stop the execute function
    pass

bot.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `task` using [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) and then cancel it using `task.cancel()`. To maintain organization and allow you to have simultaneous tasks on different channels, I recommend storing them in a dictionary, the key being the `channel_id`:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


bot = commands.Bot()
tasks = dict()


async def execute_function(ctx: commands.Context, timer: int):
    # Countdown from time given
    for i in range(timer, 0, -1):
        if int(i) == 1:
            await ctx.send(f"Execution in {i} minute")
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            await ctx.send(f"EXECUTE EXECUTE EXECUTE")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Execution in {i} minutes")
            await asyncio.sleep(60)


@bot.command()
async def execute(ctx: commands.Context, timer: int):
    if ctx.channel.id in tasks:
        await ctx.reply("There is already a task running on this channel.")
        return
    task = asyncio.create_task(execute_function(ctx, timer))
    tasks[ctx.channel.id] = task
    try:
        # Wait until the task is finished
        await task
        # If the task is cancelled, asyncio.CancelledError will be raised
        # and the next line will not be executed.
        await ctx.reply("Task completed successfully.")
    finally:
        # Ensure that the task will be removed
        # freeing up the channel for the execution of new tasks
        tasks.pop(ctx.channel.id)
    

@bot.command()
async def abort(ctx: commands.Context):
    task = tasks.get(ctx.channel.id)
    if task is None:
        return await ctx.reply("No task running on this channel.")

    # This will kill/stop the execute function
    task.cancel()
    await ctx.reply("Task canceled successfully.")


bot.run()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was wanting to do :)