# Python discordpy asyncio sleep

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a command that will cancel the "barrel timer". I have tried multiple different ways and can't seem to get this to work. I'm fairly new to programming and python together so any help will be appreciated.

```
@client.command()
async def barrels(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

   
    task = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(10))
    ctx.task = task
    await ctx.send("The Barrel timer has started.")

    
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        await ctx.send("The timer has been canceled.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} The barrels are almost ready to be picked up!")



@client.command()
async def barrelsc(ctx):
    if hasattr(ctx, 'task') and not ctx.task.done():
        ctx.task.cancel()
        del ctx.task
        await ctx.send("The timer has been canceled.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("No timer to cancel.")
```

I've tried using different looks and if statements etc. Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: My answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096041/python-discord-bot-kill-stop-another-running-function/76096360#76096360) show how to create and cancel tasks in a discord bot .

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about cancelling the sleep in the middle of it, you could simply do `await asyncio.sleep(10)`
If you want to have a command to cancel it, you could do something like this:

```py
sleep_task = None

async def sleep_task_func(ctx):
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        await ctx.send("timer has cancelled")
    

@client.command()
async def barrels(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author
   
    task = asyncio.create_task(sleep_task_func(ctx))
    
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        await ctx.send("The timer has been canceled.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} The barrels are almost ready to be picked up!")


@client.command()
async def barrelsc(ctx):
    if sleep_task and not sleep_task.done():
        sleep_task.cancel()
    else:
        await ctx.send("No timer to cancel.")
```

Also, if you need this regularly, consider using [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: why do you define `sleep_task` as `None`, and then create a function with the same name?

Comment: oh sorry that's a typo causing misunderstanding

Comment: so what do you mean?